# Why not set covariant as default when define subtype in Scala?

Tags: scala, variant, covariant

It means define `trait Option[T]` is same as `trait Option[+T]`.

It's easy to consider `val humanOpt: Option[Human]` can point to a `Option[Student]` instance just like `val humanOpt: Human` can point to a `Student` instance.

#### Maybe it seems some strange but why I consider this?

Java variable default as polymorphism which compare with c++ that it should use `virtual` keyword.I think its a important point to simplify OO in Java.

Scala use high order type in many use case that is more frequently compare to Java, such as `Option`, `Try` or define a `Cache[T]` by ourselves.

Besides, it still comply with Liskov Substitution principle.

I just want to know why not simplify covariant as default behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or define a Cache[T] by ourselves

If your `Cache` has a `put(T)` method, it can't be covariant, exactly because of the Liskov substitution principle.

```
val humanCache: Cache[Human] = new Cache[Student] // legal if cache is covariant
humanCache.put(new Professor) // oops, we put a Professor into a Cache[Student]
```

So making all types covariant by default simply won't work.

You could use variance inference instead: if type can be covariant make it covariant, if it can be contravariant make if contravariant, if neither make it invariant. But then just adding a method can change the variance and break a lot of code using your type. By making all variance explicit you are forced to notice when you do that.

Comment: Yes, the `put` method will broken covariant principle. With a question here, is there are common ways to make sure we can define a class which is  `+T` type parameter? Such as avoid `put` method when implement `Cache[+T]`.

Comment: It is allowed to be the return type of a member, a covariant parameter of the return type, or a contravariant parameter of an argument type.

Comment: @LoranceChen: You mentioned the Liskov Substitution Principle in your question. The LSP *is* precisely what tells you when you are allowed to make a type co- or contravariant in a type parameter.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I have check LSP by `Function[-T, +R]`, it's very useful.